# Compilation error using maven: "annotation are not supported in -source 1.3"

Tags: rest, maven

I had created a Restful web service simple project using the Eclipse. When I try to compile it, I'm getting the following error.

Not sure why the annotations are not supported, I did the same using the NetBeans IDE,
and it worked fine without any issue.

```
**[INFO] Compilation failure
C:\Users\gopc\workspace\RestfulService\src\restfu\Hello.java:[18,1] error: annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Trace
org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException: Compilation failure
C:\Users\gopc\workspace\RestfulService\src\restfu\Hello.java:[18,1] error: annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:715)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
C:\Users\gopc\workspace\RestfulService\src\restfu\Hello.java:[18,1] error: annotations are not supported** in -source 1.3
```

This is my pom file structure:

**POM file**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>RestfulService</groupId>
  <artifactId>RestfulService</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/build/classes</outputDirectory>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>

</build>

<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>jersey-server</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/jersey-server-1.4.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>javax-ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax-ws</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/javax.ws.rs.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

**Hello.java**

```
package restfu;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

// Plain old Java Object it does not extend as class or implements 
// an interface

// The class registers its methods for the HTTP GET request using the @GET annotation. 
// Using the @Produces annotation, it defines that it can deliver several MIME types,
// text, XML and HTML. 

// The browser requests per default the HTML MIME type.

//Sets the path to base URL + /hello
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

  // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String sayPlainTextHello() {
    return "Hello Jersey";
  }

  // This method is called if XML is request
  @GET
  //@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
  @Produces("application/xml")
  public String sayXMLHello() {
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
  }

  // This method is called if HTML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public String sayHtmlHello() {
    return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
        + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
  }

  // This method is called if JSON is request
  @GET
  //@Produces("appplication/json")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public String sayJsonHello() {
    return "{ \"HTML\": { \"title\": \"Hello Jersey\", \"body\": { \"h1\": \"Hello Jersey\" }}" ;
  }    
}
```

Comment: Which version of Maven are you using?

Comment: **C:\Users\gopc>mvn -version**
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-07 03:16:01+0800)
Java version: 1.7.0_09
Java home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7" version: "6.1" arch: "x86" Family: "windows"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add java version **1.5 or above** in `pluginManagement` (if possible in the parent pom):

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Answer (score 8):

Enhance your pom with the following:

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

You need to give at least 1.5 but better would be 1.6.

I would suggest not to change the default locations of source code. Better move your source code into the default location of maven: src/main/java and remove the configuration from your pom:

```xml
<build>
   <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>
   <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
</build>
```

Comment: after adding the source and target to 1.6, the annotation compilation error has gone, but it could not able to resolve the import of external jar in the libraries.                                                        for eg:                                                                           [ERROR] /C:/Users/gopc/workspace/RestfulService/src/restfu/Hello.java:[3,19] package javax.ws.rs does not exist

Comment: Maybe you have to add an supplemental [dependency](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|javax.ws.rs) ?

Comment: what does the supplemental dependency mean... i had posted the maven dependencies pom file in this post, please help me up..

Answer (score 0):

thanks i created the lib folder in the basedir then copied the library files into it, then added the dependency as follows, then compilation problem is resolved 
and it created the jar file and the class files.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>jersey-server</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/jersey-server-1.4.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax-ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax-ws</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/javax.ws.rs.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>
```